# Why does Boto3 download a file with another name?

Tags: python, django, docker

I'm working on a project that works when run manually, but putting the code in a docker container changes my file extension.
The code with which I am downloading the file is:

```
def download_file(filename):
    try:
        s3 = boto3.client('s3')
        s3.download_file(os.getenv('BUCKET_NAME'), filename,os.getenv('LOCAL_FILE_NAME'))
        return True, "File downloaded successfully"
    except Exception as e:
         return False, str(e)
```

Within the local variables I define the folder where the file will be stored:

```
LOCAL_FILE_NAME = tmp/file_to_process.pdf
```

When doing the test, download the file with the following extension

```
tmp/file_to_process.pdf.50Cansdf
tmp/file_to_process.pdf.B0CnBB1d
tmp/file_to_process.pdf.A0CaDB1d
```

Comment: Can you put a print statement to confirm that your `env` variable is not altered in some way? Also, can you confirm that you already didn't have the same file?

Comment: Does your files have any weird chars in them, I expect its not actually called `file_to_process.pdf`